# i am getting error ::List index out of bounds: 3

Tags: apex

```
public class armstrongnumber {
    list<Integer> rem = new list<Integer>();
    public void input(Integer num) {
        Integer reminder;
        while (num != 0) {
            reminder = math.mod(num, 10);
            rem.add(reminder);
            num = num / 10;
        }
        Integer sum = 0;
        for (Integer i = 0; i <= rem.size(); i++) {
            Integer a = rem.get(i);
            Integer cube = a*a*a;
            sum = sum + cube;
        }
        if (num == sum) {
            system.debug('the number is armstrong');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to set `Integer i = 0; i < rem.size(); i++`. You are trying to access the element that is on rem.size() position, because you set it as `i <= rem.size()`. That is why you are out of boundaries of array.

Also you do not need the list at all, it is better to skip this step in order to reduce space it takes.

Also you are attempting to assert equality of initial num and sum in the end if, but you have your num modified in while loop.

Here is the code you need:

```
public class armstrongnumber {
    public void input(Integer num) {
        Integer initialNum = num;
        Integer sum = 0;
        Integer reminder;
        while (num != 0) {
            reminder = math.mod(num, 10);
            sum += (reminder * reminder * reminder);
            num = num / 10;
        }

        if (initialNum == sum) {
            system.debug('the number is armstrong');
        }
    }
}
```